# How does a virtual address get created?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, kernel

When you compile / link say a C program, the symbols get replaced with their virtual address. How does the compiler know what virtual address each symbol should have? And is it the job of the linker or the compiler?

Comment: What have you tried to find out yourself? Why did the texts you found not help you? Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question to add some context.

Comment: linker.  See https://www.iecc.com/linker/

Comment: It makes them up.